# PowerShell: How to display arrays in CheckListBox

Tags: arrays, forms, powershell

I'm trying to make arrays which lead to different files on my computer. Then I want to display the arrays in a check box, so I can just click and open my files from there.
The array can be static, but would be nice if I could add new stuff dynamically.

```
$menulist.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$menulist.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 24
$menulist.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$menulist.Name = "menulist"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 328
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 235
$TemplateArray = $template1,$template2;
$template1 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test.tx
$template2 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test2.txt
$menulist.Items.AddRange($TemplateArray)
$menulist.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$menulist.TabIndex = 7
```

Comment: Where is your `$Form.ShowDialog();` or something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21009953/897326 Generally speaking, when it comes to showing forms, you should consider switching to C#/WinForms app, because it's much more simple over there, and you are using .NET anyway, whether from Powershell or C#, the only difference is syntax simplicity, and Visual Studio which helps you build.

Comment: at the very top. This is just the checklist section. Thank you for the link. That's how I started out. But if try to "link" the arrays, it doesn't show them anymore.

Comment: Can you post the whole code section? Then we'd be able to copy/paste to our favorite editor here and give it a try. `$TemplateArray = $template1,$template2;` <-- this does not make much sense to me, especially since you (re)define `$template1,$template2;` after.

Comment: [Code in Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TdvrDQME) here you go

Comment: This is pure winforms, why can't you go with plain old C# WinForms app? In other words, why do you need Powershell? BTW, you posted code, what is the problem with it? You never specified.

Comment: The idea is that '$template1' is a direct link to my fille and '$TemplateArray = $template1,$template2;' collect all the static links in one place, to make the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we are still discussing what you need, I'll take a guess:

```
$TemplateArray = $template1,$template2;
$template1 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test.tx
$template2 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test2.txt
```

Notice above - `$template1` and `$template2` are used before they are declared. You probably get two empty strings in it. Instead, initialize variables first:

```
$template1 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test.tx
$template2 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test2.txt
$TemplateArray = $template1,$template2;
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like thats what caused it to not to be displayed.